# Emulate click via adb on android 4.0.X

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to click via adb on a device with android 4.0.4. It does not have option `adb shell input tap X Y` yet. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get when you try to send the `input tap` command?

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html